# Replace a map of a building with Google Maps Android API

Tags: android, api, google-maps

Im using the latest Google Map API. What I would like to do is that I have an image of plan of a building. I would like to put this on the correct location and display this image instead of the normal map. It would kinda be like if you zoom in alot on a train station and you get more details.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an example with the official Google Maps for Android API sample code ([installation how-to](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/intro#sample_code)) called `GroundOverlayDemoActivity.java`.

You could try this and check if it is a starting point for further investigations.

Here is a screenshot of this activity:

[image]